# MysQl Grouping Data Together From Same User

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I'm trying to solve a problem that I'm pretty sure can be solved with a simple query I cant figure out. This is the table ve_messages:

```
MessageID | RecieverID | SenderID | Message | SentOn
```

I use a while statement to display the messages and create dynamic bootstrap panels but the query below will generate one panel every time the user receives a message. I'm trying to gather all the messages from the same user inside one panel instead so that the users can view all the messages that were sent so that they can follow the conversation. How can I do that? I tried `GROUP BY SenderID` but then I cannot access all the messages...

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
       <?php 
       $i=1;
        $inboxmsgQ="SELECT * FROM ve_messages m JOIN ve_users u ON m.SenderID=u.UserID WHERE m.RecieverID= '$loginid_session' ";
        $inboxmsgresult=mysqli_query($db,$inboxmsgQ);
        while($inbox=mysqli_fetch_array($inboxmsgresult)){$i++?>
      <?php 
      $checkavatareview=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM ve_photos p WHERE p.UserID={$inbox['SenderID']} AND IsPrimaryPhoto='1' ORDER BY InsertDate LIMIT 1");
       $rowviewe = mysqli_fetch_array($checkavatareview,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseM<?=$i;?>"><?=$inbox['ProfileName'];?> | <?=$inbox['SentOn'];?></a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseM<?=$i;?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
               <a href="profile.php?viewuserprofile=<?=$inbox['SenderID'];?>" >
              <?php if(mysqli_num_rows( $checkavatareview)==0):?>
          <img style="width: 15% !important;" class="tableimg" src="uploads/nophoto.png" alt="profilename">
              <?php elseif(mysqli_num_rows( $checkavatareview)>0):?>
           <img style="width: 15% !important;" class="tableimg" src="core/<?=$rowviewe['PhotoPath'];?>" alt="profilename">
           <?php endif;?>
          </a>
            <hr>
   <?=$inbox['Message'];?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php };?>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you using AJAX to get the new messages? Are you using jQuery? Basically, test to see if the user's pane exists, and if not add it. If it does exist, get a reference to it, and add the new data to the panel object.

Comment: @SloanThrasher: Neither Ajax or jQuery. Simple Php. I thought about testing if the pane was there with a query... How would you do it?

Comment: Since you are building the panes in PHP, you can't "test" if the pane exists -- you would know because you're creating them. Instead, you should use the order by to group the messages together, and do a break-sort when rendering them.

Answer (score 0):

To get all people the current user has received messages from (broken into multiple lines for readability - you can put it in one line in your code):

```
SELECT SenderID, ProfileName
  FROM ve_messages m JOIN ve_users u ON m.SenderID=u.UserID
 WHERE m.RecieverID= '$loginid_session'
 GROUP BY UserId, ProfileName
;
```

Loop through these results to create your panels.

You'll need a second loop within each panel to show each message, using the results of this query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ve_messages m JOIN ve_users u ON m.SenderID=u.UserID
 WHERE m.RecieverID= '$loginid_session'
   AND m.SenderID = {$inbox['SenderID']}
 ORDER BY SentOn DESC
;
```

You may actually want to change the name of the `$inbox` associative array, as it now just has the ID and profile names of senders.

The `ORDER BY` assumes that you'd want the most recent messages at the top; change `DESC` to `ASC` to flip that.